# How can I sent an array with $.ajax - dataType: json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

Im currently trying to sent a javascript array to my .php file handler and save it to my database.

The request is successful however it seems my array doesn't get POSTED / saved correctly.
In my POST request source it just turns up as: `round_items%5B%5D=1`

What am I missing?

```
id = 5;
var roundChallenges = new Array("item1", "item2", "etc");

//Save the data
var url = path.php;

var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { uid: id, round_items: roundChallenges },

    success: function(data)
    {....
```

Comment: Please learn the difference between `Java` and `javascript` before you proceed.

Comment: Are you using json_decode on php side?

Comment: the `dataType` property relates to the type of the response data *from* the server and not the request data sent *to* the server.

Comment: Also you aren't sending JSON

Answer (score 1):

`round_items%5B%5D=1` is correct.  That is what it should be sending.  That decodes to `round_items[]=1`, which is how you make arrays in query strings.

When you pass an object to `$.ajax`, jQuery converts it to a query string, a standard transport format.

In PHP, you don't need `json_decode` or anything.  It will parse it into `$_POST` for you.  `$_POST['round_items']` will be an array, and `$_POST['uid']` will be your `id`.